# How to resolve Current Directory when running Coded UI

Tags: c#, dll, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am running a CodedUI test that references a DLL and that DLL refrences a sort of "config" file.  While running the test the current Directory returns the one where CodedUI puts the test results files I've used

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

and

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

and

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

These all give me the same path

What I need is to get the path where the DLL resides because that is where the config file will be built.

The location where this will be changes if I am debugging or if I am just running the test (obviously) so I can't use that and navigate backwards or anything like that.

Are there any other ways to get the location of the DLL you are referencing??

**Edit:**

I am referencing this config file from inside the DLL that i am referencing.

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far the only place I have found the original path to the test dll is in a private variable in the test context.  I ended up using reflection to get the value out and make it usable.

```
    using System.Reflection;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    public static string CodeBase(
        TestContext testContext)
    {
        System.Type t = testContext.GetType();
        FieldInfo field = t.GetField("m_test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object fieldValue = field.GetValue(testContext);
        t = fieldValue.GetType();
        PropertyInfo property = fieldValue.GetType().GetProperty("CodeBase");
        return (string)property.GetValue(fieldValue, null);
    }
```

I used this to get the path to the DLL that is getting run and use that to then run the application that I know is compiled to the same location as the test was at.

If anyone finds a better way of getting this, please let me know as well.

Comment: I've also just implemented embedded resources in order to accomplish the same task but this is great! I wonder why Microsoft decided to implement tests in such a way...

Comment: I just want everyone to know who uses this, the path returned is usually your build location and if you are in the process of running a test that uses the path returned from this, and you try to do a new build at the same time, the files will be locked while they are being run and you could cause the test to fail or the compile to fail or both.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the directory of where a given DLL was loaded from is to use the following on a type that is defined in that assembly.

```
var type = typeof(TypeInThatAssembly);
var path = Path.GetDirectory(type.Location);
```

The `CodeBase` and `Location` property often return the same information but are very different

- CodeBase: This contains the location for the assembly as it was referenced during load
- Location: This is where the assembly was actually loaded from on disk

These can differ in application which use shadow copied assemblies (Asp.Net, xUnit, etc ...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is getting me the same path as the other two functions. I may need to clarify more.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because it's being copied and then loaded not the other way arround